# GA4 Debug View not showing hits for one subdomain: What could be causing this issue?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I can't see events for a specific subdomain in GA4 debug view even though in GTM the tags have fired and a number of hits were sent to the correct measurement ID. [GA hits sent successfully in GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY6az.png)

I have no problem seeing events from other subdomains and cross-domains. I also see the hostname of the subdomain and other data for it in reports. It seems that I'm only have issues in debug view for this specific subdomain and can't understand why.

GA4 automatically detects subdomains so I'm not sure what the problem could be and what I can even try to fix it. The events normally show up in debug view if the tags have fired and hits were sent. It can't be due to internal traffic either because I can see events for other subdomains no problem.

Comment: at the front-end, have you controlled if the event has been set to get activated in specific moment etc.?